# "If I would like to come I would rejected" is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is grammatically correct to say:

> "If I would like to come I would rejected"

Answer (score 0):

No.

> If I would like to come I would rejected

I would argue this sentence is not grammatically correct, primarily because *would* requires a present form of the verb e.g. like *reject* in *would reject*. A second point is that there is no semantic context here. Therefore, it is difficult to provide a *correct* formulation of the sentence, which is perhaps implied by the question.

So based on the limited information you provided:

"If I would like to come I would reject [...]"

Comment: The present form can be "reject" or "reject**s**". The common term for the plain form of a verb after a modal auxiliary is 'bare infinitive'.

Answer (score 0):

No, but not just for the reasons given by @Jonathan Komar.
First of all there needs to be another verb between would and rejected : "be".
It might be possible to rephrase the sentence using both "would like" and "would be rejected" but the two uses of the word would in one short sentence are always going to sound awkward. You could get round that by using "If I wanted to come I would be rejected". That is grammatically correct but still a little puzzling. Why would you be rejected? Would you be rejected just for wanting to come? Do you want to come but fear rejection?
My guess is that your thought is "Even if I wanted to come, I would be rejected" implying that the next thought is "So that is why I am not going to apply". Without more context it is hard to advise further.

Comment: Your answer, while valid, assumes the intended voicing is passive. It is not clear from the OP that this is intended. I am leaving this comment only because you referenced my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> "If I would like to come I would rejected"

is broken in more than one place. The most obvious mistake is that:

> I would rejected

should be

> I would **be** rejected

(maybe OP is "Russianer Speaker" also :) )

So the sentence becomes:

> If I would like to come I would be rejected

which is grammatically correct, but does not really make much sense.

---

Depending on the intention, the correct ways could be:

> - If I would come, I would be rejected

(implies the certainty of rejection in the case of going)

or

> - If I would like to come, I would accept the invitation. But I do not like to come.

(quite unnatural)

or:

> - I would like to come, but I am afraid I would be rejected

(implies fear of rejection)